# Get the Id of the checkbox Item Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a view where I select *"checkbox"* an Item and then click the button *"Next"* which will send a post request with the Id of the selected Item so I can use its Id to redirect to an action that requires an Id

This is the View

```
@model IEnumerable<Game>;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Game Select List";
}
<form method="post">
    <div class="card-body sm">
        <div class="card-deck">
            @foreach (var game in Model)
            {
                var photoPath = "~/image/" + (game.PhotoUrl ?? "noImage.png");
                <div id="crta" class="card m-3" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width:30%;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>@game.Name</h3>
                        <h1 hidden>@game.Id</h1>
                    </div>
                    <img class="card-img-top " height="400" title="@game.Name"
                         src="@photoPath" asp-append-version="true">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <label asp-for="@game.IsSelected"></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@game.IsSelected" asp-for="@game.IsSelected"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the action

```
        [HttpGet]       
        public IActionResult SelectGame()
        {
            var model = gameRepository.GetAllGames();           
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]       
        public IActionResult SelectGame(int id)
        {
            var game = gameRepository.GetById(id);
            if(game==null)
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(game.IsSelected==true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = game.Id });
                }

            }
            return View(game);
        }
```

It returns null.

I tried

```
<a asp-controller="home" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@game.id">Select</a>
```

But I don't like how each item will get its *"select button"*  I don't know how to call the *game.id* outside the foreach loop to use it instead of the post request!

The final result would be as this: You click a button then a modal with the game list will get call then you select a game from it and then you click next which will redirect you to the next modal(<= this view needs an id)

Comment: It looks like you code wouldn't post a parameter named `id` to your post action. It would probaby post all the checkbox value (because they are all in the form) and the name would not be `id`. If you want to post a single selected id then you should probably write some javascript to get the value and make an ajax call to post the single value

Comment: Try removing "@" in asp-for's. I'm surprised the code compiles with it there. The value there should be your **game.IsSelected** property only with no at symbol.

Comment: Also, do you have **[BindProperty]** annotation for **game** / **game.IsSelected**? Only way the post will grab it I believe.

Comment: I model bind IsSelected by putting [BindProperty]. Now when I check one box and click next the query string turns into this' SelectGame?game.IsSelected=false&game.IsSelected=false&game.IsSelected=false&game.IsSelected=false&....'

Comment: Just noticed the checkboxes were in a foreach. That probably explains the URL. Each checkbox is a separate parameter. Check [this page](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes) to help with next steps. I think you'll be all set after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create a view where I select "checkbox" an Item and then
> click the button "Next" which will send a post request with the Id of
> the selected Item so I can use its Id to redirect to an action that
> requires an Id

For this situation, you can trigger a js event when you click the submit button. In this event, **you can add a hidden input control, assign the name to the `id`(the same as the parameter name in SelectGame action), and assign the value to the id of the currently selected picture `Id`**.

> I don't know how to call the game.id outside the foreach loop to use
> it instead of the post request!

You can add a custom attribute `data-id` to each checkbox and assign it to `@game.Id`, so that in jquery, you can cycle through all the checkboxes to determine which one is selected, and get id value from the selected checkbox `data-id` attribute to hidden input control value.

And it should be noted that you should ensure that the user can **only select one of the checkboxes**, not multiple selections, otherwise the last id in the selected picture will always be passed.

In your post `SelectGame` action, the last sentence of `return View(game);` will be an error, because **the game is currently a single data of Game object, and the view received by the SelectGame corresponding model is a list object:`IEnumerable<Game>`**.

Just try the following code, which solve all these issues:

```
       [HttpPost]       
        public IActionResult SelectGame(int id)
        {
            var game = gameRepository.GetById(id);
            if(game==null)
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(game.IsSelected==true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = game.Id });
                }

            }
            List<Game> games = new List<Game>() { game };
            return View(games);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Game>;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Game Select List";
}
<form method="post">
    <div class="card-body sm">
        <div class="card-deck">
            @foreach (var game in Model)
            {
                var photoPath = "~/OrderImage/" + (game.PhotoUrl ?? "noImage.png");
                <div id="crta" class="card m-3" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width:30%;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3>@game.Name</h3>
                        <h1 hidden>@game.Id</h1>
                    </div>
                    <img class="card-img-top " height="400" title="@game.Name"
                         src="@photoPath" asp-append-version="true">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <label asp-for="@game.IsSelected"></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@game.IsSelected" data-id="@game.Id" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick='submitform()'>Next</button>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);//allow only one checkbox can be selected.
            }
        });
        function submitform() {
            var id = 0;
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    id = $(this).attr("data-id");// get selected image Id to variable id.
                }
            });
            $('<input type="hidden" name="id"/>').val(id).appendTo('form'); // add hidden input to form to pass selected image Id.
            $("form").submit();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking some of your valuable time to come up with a solution to this problem. I appreciate it!

Comment: As I can see in your GIF it works as I imagined it, the problem is when I copied your code, I got a different reaction. Now when I select a game and then I press next, it renders the same view but only the selected game shows. I then  select it again and press next but it just deselect and render the same view over and over again until I don't check the box then I get Not found view.

Comment: @MrWorldwide, I just provided this code based on the code you provided, so what do you want to see when you click next after selecting a game? You can elaborate, and then I will modify the code.

Comment: I have fixed the Issue just now! I removed 
`List<Game> games = new List<Game>() { game }; return View(games);`
and replaced it with  return `RedirectToAction("details", new { id = game.Id });` It seems to work now! Thank you so much for you help, I'm so happy right now! You really have helped me a lot, once again thank you!

Comment: Now it logs me out when I get redirect to the details action. I'll see what I can do about this. Thank you again. You are awesome!

Comment: I have solved it by changing the name of the hidden input "id" 
`$('<input type="hidden" name="id"/>').val(id).appendTo('form'); `  and in the post request too. I had this happening to me a while ago when I was watching a tutorial, sometimes when I name a variable "int Id" it just doesn't work but as soon as it is changed to something else It works just fine! If you know why this behavior happens, please enlighten me.